# facebook returns Unsupported get request on some apps?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I cannot understand the behavior of Facebook: this call working perfectly

```
https://graph.facebook.com/142809522573631?callback=jQuery18309434105455875397_1369031461008&_=1369031607843
```

but returning following error

```
 ({
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request.",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
});
```

on this call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/140402456132379?callback=jQuery18308404146176762879_1369033434327&_=1369034088376
```

How can I Fix this?

Comment: In my case `142809522573631` is throwing this error and not `140402456132379`, because their is no such object in Facebook. Could you just check back again if same is happening with you?

Comment: i have created a new app on facebook which gives me 142809522573631 this application id now when i tried to call it using graph api call then i am receiving unsupported get request error as mention above.

Comment: Is your app with id `142809522573631` in sandbox mode?

Comment: yes this app is in Sandbox Mode it is also mention there (Only visible to Admins, Developers and Testers)
Is that an issue???

Comment: Yup, that is where the problem is coming from.

Comment: how to change sandbox mode? I am unable to change it.

Comment: You will have to navigate to your app settings page and then select `disabled` for for **Sandbox Mode**, and save the settings

Comment: thanx alot u save my life i have been suffering with this issue almost from 2 months. thanx alot again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are getting error for `Unsupported get request.`, then this means that the object is either not available or is having some restrictions due to which you can't perform a `GET` on the Object. As per your comments this was because the ID you were using corresponded to an application which was having **Sandbox Mode** enabled.

To solve your issue you should navigate to your app settings page and then select **disabled** for **Sandbox Mode**, and save the settings.